# Apache only for certain things, rest lighttpd

Tags: apache-2.2, lighttpd

right now the script I'm running isn't fully functional with lighttpd, and some processes still need to be run by apache.

therfore, i was wondering if anyone could tell me how to use apache to handle cgi-bin requests on port 81 or 8080 and lighttpd on port 80.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the apache port to 8080 or 81 (In main conf and also in VirtualHost) and then enable mod_proxy in lighttpd server.modules section. You can then define proxy.server section to forward particular requests to apache.

http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs:ModProxy

Comment: You can use any unused port. 8080 or 81, its upto your choice :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "Listen 80" and subsequent VirtualHost definitions from Apache, and then configure lighthttpd to run on port 80. Note that you'll probably have a rough time maintaining session state between the two instances, but maybe that isn't a requirement for you.

Comment: so would i change it to listen 81? / listen 8080?